# Getting Arguments for PHP Script within CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm trying to pass arguments to a PHP script as I run it in CLI. I've been using the following code to do so...

```
// Set argument variables
// A is the filetype
// B is the filename and directory
$arguments = getopt("a:b:");

// If we're importing pies...
if($arguments['a'] == 'pies') {
    echo 'File Conversion and Import of PIES Data Beginning Now...' . "\n\n";
}
```

And the command would look something like this...:

```
php fileimport.php -a pies -b /filepath/filename.xml
```

I've seen arguments passed in other ways though (for other scripts) such as...

```
php fileimport --type=pies --path=filepath/filename.xml
```

Personally I prefer that method but I don't know how to code my PHP script to collect these arguments, let alone expect them. I'm sure it is ridiculously easy and I'm sorry if I've missed the obvious, but I'm hoping to get some direction here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php):

```
$shortopts  = "";

$longopts  = array(
    "type:",
    "path:",
);
// Get command line arguments
$options = getopt($shortopts, $longopts);
echo 'Input Options: ', PHP_EOL;
var_dump($options);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
    $a=$argv[1];
    $b=$argv[2];

?>
```

and your CLI Call should be

`php fileimport.php TEST1 TEST2`